# Slack send notification with attached file

Tags: go, slack-api

I want to send a Slack notification with an attached file. This is my current code:

```
package Message

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "github.com/ashwanthkumar/slack-go-webhook"
)

func Message(message string, cannalul string, attash bool) {
    f, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
      return false
    }
    defer f.Close()

    _  = f

    fullName := "myServer"
    webhookUrl := "https://hooks.slack.com/services/......."

    attachment1 := slack.Attachment {}
    //attachment1.AddField(slack.Field { Title: "easySmtp", Value: "EasySmtp" }).AddField(slack.Field { Title: "Status", Value: "Completed" })
    if attash {
        attachment1.AddField(slack.Field { Title: "easySmtp", Value: fullName})
    }
    payload := slack.Payload {
      Text: message,
      Username: "worker",
      Channel: cannalul,
      IconEmoji: ":grin:",
      Attachments: []slack.Attachment{attachment1},
    }
    err := slack.Send(webhookUrl, "", payload)
    if len(err) > 0 {
      fmt.Printf("error: %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

My code works, but I don't know how I can add an attached file in my current code. How I can do this?

Comment: It looks like you're already adding attachments in your current code. What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: @Flimzy the file is not not appended to attashed function, i don't know i i can do that

Comment: Then your code is _not_ working.  Please explain the exact problem you're facing, what you see happening, and what you expected instead. Your question, as worded, is completely misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not attach a file to an attachment through a webhook in Slack. That functionality does not exist in Slack.

If its just text you can add the content as part of the message or another attachments (up to a limit of currently 500,000 characters, which will soon be reduced to 40,000 - see [here](https://api.slack.com/changelog/2018-04-truncating-really-long-messages) for reference).

Or you can directly upload a file to a channel with the API method [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload).